# Get currently focused element/control in a WPF window

Tags: .net, wpf, focus

How can I acquire the currently focused element/control in WPF from code that is part of neither a window nor a user control?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

It depends on the type of focus you are after, `Logical` or `Keyboard`.

- **Keyboard focus** refers to the element that **currently** receives keyboard input. Only one element in the entire desktop can have keyboard focus.
- **Logical focus** refers to the element in a focus scope that **would** receive the keyboard input, **if** the focus scope was active.

Usually the Logical Focus is the element which last received keyboard focus on that focus scope. A focus scope might be an app, a form, a top level window, a tab and so forth. In other words, logical focus is how a form or window remembers which control last had the keyboard focus.

`FocusManager` gets the element with logical focus within the specified focus scope, in this case the Window (`this`):

```
IInputElement focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
```

`Keyboard` will return the element with the current keyboard input focus:

```
IInputElement focusedControl =  Keyboard.FocusedElement;
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I end up using the first option with combination of Application.Current.Windows[0] instead of 'this'.

Comment: See [System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.FocusedElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focusedelement.aspx) and [System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604088.aspx)

Comment: The [documentation on focus in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/focus-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is very good and worth a read too.