# Is it possible to detect which element is focused when focus changes?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm developing an application in WPF in which I'm trying to control tab order. For that purpose, I'm deleting tab control of these elemnents that don't need to have a tab stop with this:

```
KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
```

But I'm loosing a tab somewhere, and I was wondering if there is a way to check which exact element gained focus at each focus change.

I searched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392036/get-currently-focused-element-control-in-a-wpf-window), but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Any idea on how to detect each focused element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is only required at design time, it seems a programmatic solution is not required so one option is to use [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

By attaching Snoop to your WPF application, you will be able to to see which element currently has focus. The focused element also appears as a clickable link, which you may click to see the exact location within the visual tree.

[image: Snoop Screenshot]

If you look at the bottom of this Snoop you can see the currently focused element is a `ComboBox` called "AvailableDevicesComboBox".

Comment: @Sonhja I wouldn't say weird, I use snoop to debug WPF almost every time I do WPF design work! I'm glad it helped you :)

Comment: For me it's weird because I don't use external tools for debugging, but I have to say this will become one of the "must have"!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I think people who will search for an answer to this question should know that now Visual Studio provides users with a tool called "*Track Focused Element*" in "*Live Visual Tree*".

[image: Enable Live Visual Tree]

[image: Select Track Focused Element]

It highlights the currently focused element in your app. This tool really helped me in debugging app and fixed a really annoying bug.